# Is the hardcore auction house separate from the normal auction house?

Tags: diablo-iii

My understanding is that stash, gold, etc etc is isolated between softcore and hardcore characters. However, I'm curious if hardcore AH is separate from softcore AH.

If not, then obviously this opens up for money-and-item-transfers to hardcore characters through the auction house (publishing extremely cheap auctions etc), which seems to be what Blizzard wants to prevent. Does anyone know?

Comment: Question should be close as there is no longer an auction house for diablo 3.

Comment: Question should not be closed. See [this answer](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/8451/50582) to your own meta question about D3.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are separate auction houses for normal and hardcore players in each of the regions, as can be seen on the [Diablo III server status page](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/status). Additionally, hardcore characters do not have access to the currency-based auction houses (Source: [Diablo Auction House FAQ, Gameplay Issues](http://us.blizzard.com/en-us/company/events/diablo3-announcement/index.html#auction:auction-faq)).

Answer (score 1):

Hardcore Auction House is separate from the Softcore Auction House, If this wasn't the case farming for items on hardcore would not be worth the risk. Also there will not be a Hardcore Real Money Auction House.